# File and Directory Named the Same PHP

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have these two pieces to my website.

`localhost/FTS/papers`  - which is a php file
`localhost/FTS/papers/` - which is a directory

What I am wanting to do is make it so that when I load:

`localhost/FTS/papers`  -or-
`localhost/FTS/papers/` -or-
`localhost/FTS/papers.php`

I want them all to go to the papers file.

Right now it is accessing the directory instead of the file which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /FTS/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/FTS/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I am putting this exact code into my /var/www/FTS/.htaccess file but it is not working for localhost/FTS/papers...

Comment: That seemed to have worked but it still has just a small couple of issues. It looks like none of the css is coming through and it just shows the website in plain html. Also it keeps changing the link to "papers/" instead of just "papers". I just to be able to take the trailing slash off as well.

Comment: For css/js better to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/` else you can try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`.

Comment: Also if `/papers/` is a real directory then trailing slash is added by `mod_dir` module not by above rule. And it is better to not take trailing slash off from a directory.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/var/www/FTS/screen.css">
This is what I currently have for my absolute path to css but its not working still. Any suggestions?

Comment: It should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/FTS/papers/screen.css">` You don't provide filesystem path here.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is rather confusing for PHP (as it also is for me) when you are talking to a papers directory or a papers document.

The best way, if possible, is to change the name of the papers document to papers_doc to ensure you that you are on the right place. (it's very error prone).

Than you can easily is the is_dir functionality of PHP to check if you are talking to a file or a directory:

```
var_dump(is_dir('a_file.txt'));
var_dump(is_dir('bogus_dir/abc'));
```

Or use is_file:

```
var_dump(is_file('a_file.txt'));
var_dump(is_file('bogus_dir/abc'));
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is place an htaccess file in the `papers` directory with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /FTS/papers.php [L]
```

And allow mod_dir to redirect `/FTS/papers` to `/FTS/papers/`.

Comment: This is working...kindof. It is no longer showing any of the graphics that I had and it is still showing the link localhost/FTS/papers/ when I want it to take the trailing slash off the end and just display the papers.php page

Comment: @FreeTheStudents Are your images relatively linked? You need to either make them absolute links or add a relative base to the header of your page (e.g. `<base href="/" />`). As for trying to make `/FTS/papers` load the php file without a redirect, it would require turning off mod_dir, which will make it so anyone can view your directory contents even if you have an index file, so that means turning off auto indexing: `Options -Indexes` and turning off mod_dir `DirectorySlash Off`

Comment: link rel="stylesheet" href="/var/www/FTS/screen.css"> This is what I currently have for my absolute path to css but its not working still. Any suggestions?

Comment: @FreeTheStudents you want it absolute in relation to the URL-path, not the file path. For example, if the css file can be reached at `http://localhost/FTS/screen.css`, then you need to make it `/FTS/screen.css`